# Real world applications of the study of Egyptian Fractions

Tags: egyptian-fractions

I recently read about the study of [Egyptian Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) on the [Good Math, Bad Math](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2006/11/15/egyptian-fractions/) blog. The references to this article show that many years of research have gone into trying to find efficient ways to calculate the minimum length forms.

Are there any real-world applications that computing minimum-length Egyptian forms can be applied to?

Comment: The Wikipedia link you gave includes some applications. In particular I would say that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction#Equally_distributing_objects is a reasonable real-world application.

Comment: Good point. However, is this really the way certain products or algorithms work? Is this method used in electronics or computation somehow? Is there a business or public institution somewhere that finds the advances in minimum-length Egyptian fractions beneficial?

Answer (score 3):

Electronic circuit design is one area where Egyptian fractions have practical use. When electrical resistors are added to a parallel circuit, the reciprocals are added to find the total resistance. An example is a parallel circuit with 1,2,3, and 6 Ohm resistors.

$$\frac{2}{1\Omega}=\frac{1}{1\Omega}+\frac{1}{2\Omega}+\frac{1}{3\Omega}+\frac{1}{6\Omega}$$

Inductance (L) in Henrys (H) in parallel circuits is calculated in the same way.

$$\frac{1}{2 H}=\frac{1}{4 H}+\frac{1}{5 H}+\frac{1}{36 H}+\frac{1}{45 H}$$